# How to update text of a button in parent dialogfragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button, android-dialogfragment

I have a `dialogfragment` in the `MainActivity` and show it like this:

```
...
            AddNewPlanDialog mAddNewPlanDialog = new AddNewPlanDialog();
            mAddNewPlanDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "addNewPlanDialog");
...
```

In this `AddNewPlanDialog`, there is a button, when I click this button, it will show another `dialogfragment` to offer a list for me to select. Here is code for  `AddNewPlanDialog`.

```
public class AddNewPlanDialog extends DialogFragment {



    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater mInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_add_new_plan_dialog, null);

        Button mPriorityButton = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_new_plan_priority);


        //update priority of plan
        mPriorityButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AddNewPlanPriorityDialog mAddNewPlanPriorityDialog = new AddNewPlanPriorityDialog();
                mAddNewPlanPriorityDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "addNewPlanPriorityDialog");

            }
        });




        // set final view and final buttons
        mBuilder.setView(mView)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });

        return mBuilder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "ON ACTIVITY CALLED!!!");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

Here is code for `AddNewPlanPriorityDialog`.

```
public class AddNewPlanPriorityDialog extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        mBuilder.setTitle(R.string.pick_priority).setItems(
                R.array.add_new_plan_priority_array,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // do something
                    }
                });

        return mBuilder.create();
    }

}
```

I want to update text of `mPriorityButton` when item in `mAddNewPlanPriorityDialog` is pressed and returned.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mAddNewPlanPriorityDialog.setTargetFragment(AddNewPlanDialog.this, requestCode);` when you show the second dialog from the first (before calling `show()`).
And `((AddNewPlanDialog) getTargetFragment()).someFunction();`

instead of `// do something` in the second dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to smb's answer, this problem solves. Here are some complements.

In second dialog, invoke a function from parent `dialogfragment`, like this:

```
...
((AddNewPlanDialog)getTargetFragment()).updatePriority();
...
```

Then define this function in first dialog.

```
...
public void updatePriority(){


    Button mButton = (Button) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.btn_add_new_plan_priority);
    mButton.setText("pick me!!");

}
...
```

Now the button in the parent dialog gets updated.